Azure API Management importing openapi generating long names
I have the following openapi.json generated via java annotations, and when I import it into the azure api management portal it generates a long name like: RestApiAdminLocationSourcesGet200ApplicationJsonResponse for the definition for 200 status
How do I change it so its a specific name? I realize that the type=array is the problem. I have tried marking the name in the LocationSourcePO object but it didnt work.
Note: I cannot change the return type and wrap the array in another object
Generated openapi.json 3 snippet:
"/rest/api/admin/locationSources": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "Admin Location Source API"
    ],
    "summary": "Admin - Get all location sources",
    "description": "Get all location sources",
    "operationId": "getAllLocationSources",
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Location sources retrieved successfully",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LocationSourceResponse"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, ...
 "LocationSourcePO": {
        "required": [
          "description",
          "locationSourceCode"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "locationSourceCode": {
            "maxLength": 2147483647,
            "minLength": 1,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Location Source Code"
          },
          "description": {
            "maxLength": 2147483647,
            "minLength": 1,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Location Source Code Description"
          }
        },
        "description": "Object for the Location Source PO."
      },

Thanks
EDIT: Java code - original that generates the long name in azure api management
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Operation(
        summary = "Admin - Get all location sources",
        description = "Get all location sources for the Admin Console",
        responses = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
                        description = "Location sources retrieved successfully", content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = LocationSourcePO.class)), mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        })
public Response getAllLocationSources() {
  List<LocationSourcePO> locationSourcePOs = locationSourceHandler.getAllLocationSource();

  return Response
         .ok()
         .entity(locationSourcePOs)
         .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .build();
}

LocationSourcePO:
@Schema(name ="LocationSourcePO", description = "Object for the Location Source PO.")
public class LocationSourcePO {

@Schema(description = "Location Source Code")
private String locationSourceCode;

@Schema(description = "Location Source Code Description")
private String description;

public String getLocationSourceCode() {
    return locationSourceCode;
}

public void setLocationSourceCode(String locationSourceCode) {
    this.locationSourceCode = locationSourceCode;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}}


Yes indeed, its generating the long name by combining the array type /rest/api/admin/locationSources. So, you can explicitly define a response name by using the OpenAPI schema in the given format wherein I have added LocationSourceResponseArray of type array. You can rename it accordingly.
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Admin Location Source API",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/rest/api/admin/locationSources": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Admin Location Source API"
        ],
        "summary": "Admin - Get all location sources",
        "description": "Get all location sources",
        "operationId": "getAllLocationSources",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Location sources retrieved successfully",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LocationSourceResponseArray"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "LocationSourceResponse": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "locationSourceCode": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Location Source Code"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Location Source Code Description"
          }
        }
      },
      "LocationSourceResponseArray": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LocationSourceResponse"
        },
        "description": "An array of LocationSourceResponse objects"
      },
      "LocationSourcePO": {
        "required": [
          "description",
          "locationSourceCode"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "locationSourceCode": {
            "maxLength": 2147483647,
            "minLength": 1,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Location Source Code"
          },
          "description": {
            "maxLength": 2147483647,
            "minLength": 1,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Location Source Code Description"
          }
        },
        "description": "Object for the Location Source PO."
      }
    }
  }
}

This will generate the response name as LocationSourceResponseArray.

You can also change the definition name in below.



Thank you for your reply - I tried to make this work, however I cannot modify the return type. The new swagger displays the return model as:
{
"locationSources": {
"locationSourceCode": "string",
"description": "string"
}
}
But I want it the same as original which is:
[
{
"locationSourceCode": "string",
"description": "string"
}
]

Note: I am doing this in java, I tried both
content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = LocationSourcePOArray.class), mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
and
content = @Content(schema = @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/LocationSourceResponseArray"), mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

Can you share your complete Java code

@petula I have added the modified OpenAPI schema which will generate from the the code. I am using only content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = LocationSourceResponseArray.class)) in ApiResponse

Thanks however it changes my swagger return model to returning a named array
{ "locationSources:" [ { "locationSourceCode": "string", "description": "string" } ] } which is not what I want

@petula Modified my answer, please check
